# Socket.io chat example node.js require

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

From the [socket.io chat example.](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat)
What does it mean in the index.js:

```
var io = require('../..')(server);
```

What does '../..' means? 
I looked up the some information and some say that '../' means the index.js in the parent folder, is that correct?

I noticed that the index.js is missing `require('socket.io')(server);`

```
index.js:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

so maybe ../.. require socket.io for us too?

### Found same question on SO:

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668755/what-does-var-io-require-server-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically ../ means moving into the parent directory of current directory.So the following line means ../.. will start searching the parent of parent directory will try to access server module form the same.

```
var io = require('../..')(server);
```

Suppose currently you are in Project/fol1/fol2 folder where index.js file is located,so if you want to require a module or file in project folder then you will have to move to the path first before accessing module "../.." this will do the same.

Please refer following link question **answered by Adam** you will get clear idea.
[node.js filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055049/node-js-fs-readfile-always-returns-error/22055273#22055273)